# using native objective-c method for C callbacks

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to callback an objective c method from c.

```
//c 
int gameEngineCallback(int buttontype,void (*callback)(void))

//using above function
gameEngineCallback(roundButton,callback);

//this works fine but I want to call objective c native method instead of this
static void callback(void){

}
```

Comment: You can't. The `callback` parameter needs a function with no parameters and a void return type. You can't pass an Objective-C method.

Comment: thanks.ok can I pass c method like above including objective-c objects? I mean simply how do I control UIbutton or webview through C callback method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193857/callback-methods-from-c-to-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: Maybe it is possible with `objc_msgsend`?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't Pass Objective c method in  **C CallBack protoType** . but u can redirect to your Objective c Function from the C Call back definition.

**EXAMPLE**

//Add below line in public declaration of Your Ivar

```
id myclass; // if ur not Sure about ur class name or u have to redirect to ur delegate class

or 

YourClassName *instanceof class; //(no need to create instance just declartion)
```

// before ur call back fires Assign value  for ur IVAr in ur init definition

```
myclass = self ;
or
myclass = delegate;
```

// use above IVAR like this  in Your C callback Function

```
static void callback(void)
{

[myclass Your Function];

 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.do we have any trick to call a method from current class?

Comment: Your C Call back in ur Current Class?

Comment: then in ur .m  before @implementation declare  ur ivar like `YourClassName *myclass`;(no need to create instance just declartion) and in viewdidload assign  `myclass=self;`  and then call function  using myclass instead of 'self' inside ur Callback

Comment: How about for void * I tried to do this yesterday and closest I got would tell me there was no method by the name visible in class.

Comment: Hello Guys, I am trying to do the same. But, not able to get it.
What I want to do is, I have a callback function which is static void.
In this static callback function, I need to access my local variables and local methods. But I am not getting an access to it.
Will you please help me to out to get this ?